# What does << mean?

Tags: java, symbols

What are these double lesser than symbols. I've had to use them but I have no idea what they are. It seems to be comparing just like the == but I've never heard of it before. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Aren't you aware of bitwise operations? Also, like `==`? Just the use of them should have told you otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<< (left shift)
```

Binary Left Shift Operator. The left operands value is moved left by the number of bits specified by the right operand.

Example: Lets say A = 60. So,

```
A = ...000111100
```

A << 2 will give

```
A = ...011110000
```

which in decimal is 240.

Look at this [example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=268) to learn more.